# Erro SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, api, framework, zend

Estou tentando criar uma api na minha aplicação, porém está me retornando o seguinte erro: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Estou utilizando o Zend Framework 3.

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array("teste"=>"123"), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Será que alguma configuração do Zend está dando conflito?

Answer (score -1):

tente assim:

```
use Zend\Json\Json;
$data = array("teste"=>"123");
echo Json::encode($data);
```

ou se estiver usando Zend-Diactoros

`$data = array("teste"=>"123");`
`return new JsonResponse($data,200);`